# How to query additional rows based on the ones already existed in a result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I do believe that the subject is extremely confusing, so let's me explain my question by this small example:

Let's say I have a table of `Entity` with fileds `id, feature, group_id`. group_id is a ref key to another table

```
id | feature | group_id
-----------------------------
1  |  true   | group_1

2  |  false  | group_1

3  |  false  | group_2

4  |  true   | null
```

Could you guys suggest how to query all the records with `feature = true` and addition to it all the records within the same group irrespective of feature flag.
So from the table above the result should be `1` (because of `true`) and `2` (because it has the same group as `1` which passes our predicate)

Perhaps it's important to know, that in a real query the `feature = true` condition is hundreds of lines where/or/subselects statements (but for now, maybe, let's just focus on the aforementioned simple example).

UPDATE: I added the row with id `4` where `group_id` is null

Answer (score 2):

You could use an IN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Entity
WHERE group_id IN (SELECT group_id FROM entity WHERE feature = true)
```

In case group_id could be null for MySQL you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM Entity
WHERE IFNULL(group_id, 0) IN (SELECT IFNULL(group_id, 0) FROM entity WHERE feature = true)
```

(So it converts a NULL to 0 which means it still works with the in clause. However, make sure group_id is never 0 or this could still fail. You could use -1 instead.)

Comment: Thanks, @user1178830. I've updated a bit the original question. The group_id might be null actually. `SELECT * FROM Entity
WHERE group_id IN (SELECT group_id FROM entity WHERE feature = true) OR (group_id IS NULL AND feature=true)`. Could this be then a solution?

Comment: Well, not really, because if there are two rows with group_id = null but only one of them has feature = true, it will only show the one row. I'll update the answer with another option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT * FROM Entity E1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM Entity E2 
              WHERE E1.group_id = E2.group_id 
              AND E2.feature = 'true'
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select * from Entity where group_id in (select group_id from Entity where feature = 
'true');
```